# How to retrieve all elements text value present in the screen using selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

```
List<String> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
System.out.println("Links count is: "+allLinks.size());
for(WebElement link : allLinks)
System.out.println(link.getText());
```

Please let me know how can i read all elements text value  dynamically from dissimilar tags present in the screen

sample HTML code

```
<span id="Lbl_Code" class="cus-lbl-on">Code</span>

<label for="Chk_OpenCalls">Team Member self assignment of open calls</label>
<font color="red">*</font>
<input type="submit" name="but_save" value="Save" onclick="return 
   teamvalidate();" id="but_save" class="btn cus-btn-save">
```

Comment: All elements or all links?

Comment: I want to retrieve all elements text value (Label name)which is belongs to dissimilar tags present in the UI screen.

Comment: I have also attached HTML code for more clarifications:                                        sample HTML code 
<!--snippet-->

<span id="Lbl_Code" class="cus-lbl-on">Code</span>

<label for="Chk_OpenCalls">Team Member self assignment of open calls</label>
<font color="red">*</font>
<input type="submit" name="but_save" value="Save" onclick="return teamvalidate();" id="but_save" class="btn cus-btn-save">                <!--snippet-->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the below solution its working as expected.

```
//*[string-length(normalize-space(text())) > 0]
```

> text() Selects all strings
>
> normalize-space(text()) Selects all strings removing their spaces
>
> string-length(normalize-space(text())) > 0 Selects all texts not empty
>   strings
>
> //*[CONDICTION] searching in all document based in a condiction